# When do you do a health check?

Tags: java, design, web-applications

So, I have an application here that posts requests to another service via REST API calls. I have to implement a health check within my application that ensures that the other service is up. I'm a software noob here and my question is this:

When do I ping the other service to check if they're up? During my application startup (this is just going to be a one time thing) or when I initialize the client which makes the REST API calls to the other service?

Comment: What happens when the other service isn't up? What would your service do if the health check fails?

Comment: The answer to "when do you do a health check" is "when do you need to know the service is healthy?"

Comment: my service cannot function/do it's job since all it does is essentially make POST requests to the other service. If the other service isn't up, there's no point in going ahead with the request

Comment: What do you do if the service becomes unavailable between doing a health check and trying to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not completely agree with above answers.. I'll take the example of the readiness probe concept of Kubernetes.

The idea is that we want to avoid routing requests to the pod until it is ready to accept traffic. 
`However, the readiness probe will continue to be called throughout the lifetime of the container, every periodSeconds, so that the container can make itself temporarily unavailable when one of its dependencies is unavailable`

If you service (deployed in a container) is not capable of handle the traffic (for instance because the database is down and it is a critical dependency) it is useless to send requests to it because it will result in timeout (and so potential blocked thread), cascading failures and lot of stacktraces in console and log files..

It is exactly like the concept of circuit breakers.. `If a service can handle your requests just don't call it`. `Fail-Fast` is better than let users waiting for 5 seconds for finally send him an internal error response..

So yes all of these things applies during all the lifetime of the service but I think these should be applied too during `start-up`.

Answer (score 2):

This is like the classic I/O mistake where you test if a file exists before opening it for writing. By the time you attempt to open it, it may not exist anymore.

You test services when you use services. Not before. Testing before use, say to warn the user that the fields they’re about to fill out might be lost is dumb.  The services are free to go up or down between test and use.  It’s far better to hold the fields locally an attempt to use again.

Of course you’re free to let the user test as they like but don’t force this into their workflow. It’s completely pointless.

Comment: This makes sense - before having the user type out their info, I could do a quick check to see if the other service is up

Comment: NO! You stop assuming the service is up when you can’t know that and gracefully preserve their input client side until it is up. Let them resubmit with one button click until they stop getting error messages.

Comment: Just make that button click [idempotent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077412/what-is-an-idempotent-operation)

Comment: If that button click is trying to update multiple services at once which can’t be allowed fail independently then you have a transaction on your hands. You need to define a unit of work that can unwind the updates that succeeded when they don’t all succeed.

Comment: I'm thoroughly confused here :( The other service is basically Jenkins and my service makes POST requests to Jenkins. The way I understand this, I only check if my Jenkins instance is up and if YES, I proceed to make the POST request. Although yes, for multiple requests, it would be multiple pings to check if Jenkins is up before making the POST call :/

Comment: “Jenkins, you up?” “Yes” “Jenkins, do this post” “Jenkins is unreachable”. What happens now?

Comment: "Jenkins is unreachable" "Ok, do nothing! Send message back to user"

Comment: Yes. Don’t test and assume things are still fine later.  Try, and recover if it turns out they aren’t.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that. Seriously. Concurrent distributed systems are hard, and this is why. Testing before use ("health checks") simply builds a race condition into your system design since you can't guarantee availability anyway. The API endpoint can always fall over between test and use.

Consider that from the client's perspective there's no difference between failure because the endpoint is down and failure due to network transients. Non-availability is non-availability -- why doesn't matter to the client. Your best bet is to do something sane with the error, whether that's back off and retry, log and fail, or something else.

And while you're learning, the ACM's digital library (http://dl.acm.org) is open for all until 30 Jun. There's a solid book on Leslie Lamport's contributions to distributed computing and concurrency you can grab for free -- highly recommended.